# Classification vs Linear Regression

Tags: regression, classification

Perhaps a naive question, but consider this sort of dataset:

```
x1   x2  y
2    11  0
2.5  22  1
4    16  1
5.4  27  1
2.2  9   0
7.2  29  0
15.1 30  0
16.5 40  0
18.4 32  1
```

clearly binary classification problem! why wouldn't you use Linear Regression instead, each `y_pred` (range [0,1]) interpreted as probability of users propensity to transact (1) or not (0)

Thanks in advance for your thought!

Comment: This is a question of logistic regression versus classification.

Comment: I mean if I apply "Linear Regression" model instead "Logistic Regression"

Comment: Think of it this way. Let $f(x) = w^T x + w_0.$ If the values of your target variable, $y,$ are all $0$s and $1$s, is it more reasonable to say that it was generated by the process $y = \mathcal{N}(f(x), \Sigma)$ or by the process $y = \text{Bernoulli}(\sigma[f(x)])$?

Comment: to put Bridgeburners point in a more intuitive level: plot x1 against y, would your eye fit a straight line or an s shape like logistic regression?  I would suggest you use logistic regression (with poss non linear terms/interactions) rather than "classification", on the assumption that the probabilities are valuable business inputs...

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression models aren't great for this because they can predict values beyond 1, which isn't very useful for binary classification. Probit or logit regression models would be more suitable because they return a value between 0 and 1. You would still need to come up with some sort of decision rule to perform the actual classification based on your regression output.

You can probably achieve good results with a logistic regression + a decision rule, but there are a lot of classification techniques out there that were designed for this type of task. It all comes down to the nature of your data, but I think that you can do better than logistic regression with respect to computational cost, accuracy/precision/sensitivity/specificity, and your ability to correctly classify new data points.